# ESLint: Spacing around equal sign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm using `airbnb` for my base ESLint, but I noticed it doesn't seem to tag whitespace violations like it used too:

```
state={
```

Should raise an issue and be correct to:

```
state = {
```

Same with functions:

```
toggleSidebar=() => {
```

Which should be:

```
toggleSidebar = () => {
```

What's the rule to fix this and why did they stop flagging it?

Comment: The relevant rule seems to be space-infix-ops

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the [space-infix-ops](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/space-infix-ops) rule

Answer (score 0):

1 According to below post, it should work:
https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3299

2 According to documentation
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/space-infix-ops

Options are:

```
'space-infix-ops':['error',{ int32Hint:false }]
'space-infix-ops':['error',{ int32Hint:true }]
'space-infix-ops':'error'
```

However, unable to make it work. Possibly because I have several other settings that may be conflicting.

May be works for others, worth a try.